# JSP - List output

Tags: java, list, jsp

I currently have the following:

`cartServlet.java`

```
public class CartServlet extends HttpServlet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

CartBean cartBean = new CartBean();

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    int counter = 0;

    while (request.getParameterMap().containsKey("id" + counter)){
        String songID = request.getParameter("id" + counter);
        cartBean.setCartInfo(songID);               
        ++counter;
    }


    request.setAttribute("cart", cartBean);


    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/cart.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);


}
```

`cart.jsp`

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Shopping Cart</title>
</head>
<body>

"${cart.cartInfo}"

</body>
</html>
```

`cartBean.java`

```
public class CartBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<String> cart;

public CartBean(){
    cart = new ArrayList<String>();     
}

public void setCartInfo(String cartItem) {
    this.cart.add(cartItem);
}   

public List<String> getCartInfo() {
    return cart;
}   

}
```

When I print `"${cart.cartInfo}"`, my output is coming out like this:

`"[381d3af3-c113-46c1-b9d0-2c46cf445e22}, 3913ac54-0c03-4025-8279-5cfad2fcab5f}, 50ed6861-f6e2-479b-865c-cbbbc5c27efd}, eb9b29d6-d93e-4cd8-8d7a-7fe26ff6c05d}]"`

Is this the correct way the output should be printed out? I don't know why the additional `}` is appearing at the end of each item..

Also, should I be defining `CartBean cartBean = new CartBean();` in `cartServlet.java`? If a user were to come back to this shopping cart page and select more items, would the new items be placed in a different bean to the one I was originally using?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this the correct way the output should be printed out? I don't know
>   why the additional } is appearing at the end of each item..

I'm guessing that yes, what's being listed on your JSP is what's supposed to be listed. Now it may differ from what you *want*, which is another matter. What appears to be currently listed is the ID for a song. In this XML file, I see one of the IDs listed as for "The Sweetest Taboo" by Sade in this homework file: http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs9321/14s1/assignments/musicDb.xml.

You need to use the `useBean` tag in your JSP. The syntax is as follows:

```
<jsp:useBean id = "idName" class = "packageName.SpecificClass" scope = "desiredScope" />
```

Fill in `id`, `class`, and `scope` with the desired values. The most common value for `scope` seems to be `session`.

Then set the property:

```
<jsp:setProperty name = "idName" property = "*" />
```

For more information about `setProperty` (along with `useBean`), see: [jsp:setproperty what does property="*" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274554/jspsetproperty-what-does-property-mean).

> Also, should I be defining `CartBean cartBean = new CartBean();` in
>   `cartServlet.java`?

It's usually best to use the servlet for the bean, especially if there's some processing that's going on, like filling in lists. Avoid putting a lot of Java code in your JSPs. The JSP should be able to grab a list of products and place them on the page, but it should *not* be able to instantiate the list, populate it, massage it into the form you need, and then place the products.

> If a user were to come back to this shopping cart
>   page and select more items, would the new items be placed in a
>   different bean to the one I was originally using?

Read this page: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=53309.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the statement of creating CartBean inside doPost() method as a local variable, otherwise each request will create a new Thread and these threads share the instance variable which means the data in CartBean will be corrupted by different users.