# unable to set attributes in requests in JSP/servlets - Java?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request, requestdispatcher

Here are the steps I follow in my jsps code:
1) login page and am posting it to servlet.

2) In the servlet, I am setting up some request attributes and forward the request using dispatcher
to another to set bean property.

3) The bean set the property and forwards to a different url.

4) In this url, I pull the attributes from the request to display on page. I get a `null` out of the request, indicating that my attribute is not set on request. That is the `displayinfo.jsp` below displays **Welcome Null**. why the attribute is not set?

Here is my code:
`Login page:`

```
<form id="login" method="post" action="setBeansAllPropertiesLoginUser.do">  
    <span>UserName:</span><input name="uid" type="text" style="width:250px;" /> 
    <span>Password:</span><input name="pwd" type="password" style="width:250px;"/>
</form>
```

`servlet:`

```
@WebServlet("/setBeansAllPropertiesLoginUser.do")
public class SetBeansAllPropertiesLoginuser extends HttpServlet {

    public SetBeansAllPropertiesLoginuser() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String uid = request.getParameter("uid");
        String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");

        request.setAttribute("userId", uid);
        request.setAttribute("password", pwd);
        //verify login details
        int authLevel = 1;

        String base = "setBean.jsp";
        /*
        String params = String.format("?userId=%s&password=%s&authLevel=%d"
                , uid, pwd, authLevel);
        */
        String dest = String.format("%s%s"
                        ,base
                        ,params);
        //RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(dest);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(base);
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

`setBean.jsp`

```
<table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:25%;height:80%;" valign="top">
                <jsp:include page="navbar.jsp" />
            </td>
            <td style="width:75%;height:80%;">
                <jsp:useBean id="wu" class="com.worldmanager.models.WebUser"
                    scope="request">
                    <jsp:setProperty name="wu" property="*" />
                </jsp:useBean>

                <jsp:forward page="displayinfo.jsp" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

`displayinfo.jsp`:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:25%;height:80%;" valign="top">
                <jsp:include page="navbar.jsp" />
            </td>
            <td style="width:75%;height:80%;">
                <jsp:useBean id="wu" class="com.worldmanager.models.WebUser" scope="request"/>

                <h1>Welcome 
                    <jsp:getProperty name="wu" property="userId" />
                </h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

My `bean` is correct. I tested it. Above I pasted the code that is relevant. It is not complete code

Comment: I don't see how the attribute is related to the `userId` property of the `wu` bean. Can you clarify that?

Comment: in the setbean.jsp, I use `wu` bean for setting up the userId. and in `displayInfo`.jsp, I try to pull out from the bean..make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
<jsp:getProperty name="wu" property="userId" />
```

to

```
<c:out value="${userId}" />
```

to read it directly from request attribute

by using `<jsp:getProperty>` you are requesting `wu.getUserId()` and you haven't set `wu` 's property  in available scope

**Or**

Set `wu`'s property explicitly

```
  <jsp:setProperty name="wu" property="userId"  value="${userId}"/>
  <jsp:setProperty name="wu" property="password"  value="${password}/>
```

and access it same way as you are doing now

```
  <jsp:getProperty name="wu" property="userId" />
```

Comment: I am setting the property in `setBean.jsp`. After setting it, I am forwarding to `displayinfo.jsp`. I know it is very confusing and complex. but just for learning purposes.

Comment: you aren't setting `wu`'s property with proper names

Comment: @brainstorm If you don't want to use the core tags then use a JSP container and just use JSP EL, e.g., `${userId}`.

Comment: @Dave that is little risky to use directly without trusting its content

Comment: @JigarJoshi Yes, I made some assumptions about the value contained in the user ID and password. I assume that dev's are performing due diligence on their input data, however, until shown otherwise.

Comment: @JigarJoshi: correct me: you have indeed used EL above with `value=${userId}`?

Comment: yes I have but it is internal at server side, that is secure and fine, It gets risky if you directly try to output only

Comment: and probably what you suggested might not work because my request **parameter** does not have `userId` but I stupidly try to setAttribute of `userId` on request, which the bean will not consume...

Comment: having said that, if I have renamed my form input elements to have the same names as bean property, then what you suggested will work perfectly

Comment: it will work because you are reading it with right parameter names and setting it in request as attributes

Comment: when you say set explicity, do you mean here `setBean.jsp`. I am confused now. will $(userId) be fetched from request **parameter** or request **attribute**?

Comment: `$(userId) ` will be fetched as an attribute, I see the code where you are reading them from your login form parameter and setting it to request attribute in your `servlet`

Comment: so how would I fetch request parameter in EL? I mean is there a syntax for it or is it simply using `request.getParameter()`.  the way I did above using "*" works only when the request parameter is set but Not request attributes correct??

Comment: You are submitting a form to servlet, at servlet you are fetching request parameters and setting it to request attribute by code, and now you are forwarding your request to another jsp - this is the flow, you don't need to fetch request parameter in side jsp because you are already posting and fetching it in servlet

Comment: I understand what you say. But I am just wondering if at all it is possible to get requestParameter using EL? just like how you used $(userId) for fetching request attribute.

Comment: yes you can get request parameter in el by `${param.paramName}`

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274554/jspsetproperty-what-does-property-mean), the following notation

```
<jsp:setProperty name="wu" property="*" />
```

will retrieve and set properties based on request parameter names. So change your request parameters from

```
String uid = request.getParameter("uid");
String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");
```

to

```
String uid = request.getParameter("userId");
String pwd = request.getParameter("password");
```

Obviously change your `form`'s `input` parameter names as well.

Comment: I know I am doing it this in a complex manner. but if you notice, in the servlet, I get these parameters from request and set the new parameters in request for correct names for beans to handle. This should in theory work ?

Comment: @brainstorm Don't confuse request parameters and request attributes. The `setProperty` seems to get request **parameters**. Yours are named differently than the bean's property names.

Comment: I got confused with parameter and attributes on request. And you corrected me saying that setPropery uses request parameters. I guess there is no way to set **request parameter** and is probably not useful right?

Comment: @brainstorm When you submit a `<form>`, its elements are submitted as form parameters which a servlet container translates to **request parameters**. Just change their names appropriately and the `setProperty` element will retrieve them correctly to then set them on the bean.

Comment: what will happen if you add another parameter in form and don't intend to update bean with new property ?

Comment: @Jigar Do you mean adding a new `<input name="wtv" />` but not having a `wtv` property in the bean? I believe `setProperty` will look through all the bean's properties and try to find matching request parameters.

Comment: yes but its not precisely specified, what if it don't find matching property

Comment: I think it is clear enough to just ignore it. I have a similar case here. my bean has three property - uname,pwd, auth_level. but I set only two of them in the bean and it does not report any error

Comment: @Jigar I'm trying to find how it's handled, but I would think it skips it.

Comment: @Jigar Yeah, I give up on finding it. Should be pretty simply to test but I don't have the env right now.